# How to get all child's values from a new child using data snapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am running my app and adding a new child to firebase, online you can see all the child's values, but the data snapshot only gets the first value of the new child added.

we tried reading the child values each one separately, but it seems like the data snapshot doesn't even know they exist.

```
public static void NotifyToTripList(final NotifyDataChange<List<Trip>> notifyDataChange) {
        if (notifyDataChange != null) {
            if (tripRefChildEventListener != null) {
                notifyDataChange.onFailure(new Exception("first unNotify trip list"));
                return;
            }

            tripList.clear();
            tripRefChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
@override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {                   
                   Trip t=new Trip();
                    t.setTripID(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("DriverID").getValue()!=null) t.setDriverID(Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.child("DriverID").getValue().toString()));
                    else t.setDriverID(0L);
                    t.setDestination(dataSnapshot.child("Destination").getValue().toString());
                    t.setCurrentLocation(dataSnapshot.child("CurrentLocation").getValue().toString());
                    t.setPassengerEmail(dataSnapshot.child("PassengerEmail").getValue().toString());
                    t.setPassengerNumber(dataSnapshot.child("PassengerNumber").getValue().toString());
                    t.setPassengerName(dataSnapshot.child("PassengerName").getValue().toString());
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 
                   tripList.add(t);
                    notifyDataChange.OnDataChanged(tripList);
}
```

the code from the main menu:

```
 FireBaseDataBase.NotifyToTripList(new FireBaseDataBase.NotifyDataChange<List<Trip>>() {
            @Override
            public void OnDataChanged(List<Trip> obj) {
                FireBaseDataBase.tripList = obj;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error to get trips list\n" + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

this is what a normal ride datasnapshot looks like:

> DataSnapshot { key = -LbbpVoPNgUDi-0eTDRY, value = {Destination=Mordehai A'liash 6, Jerusalem, DriverID=666666666, PassengerNumber=0535291683, PassengerName=chana Gross, PassengerEmail=chanatriplet@gmail.com, PickUpTime=12:20:00, CurrentLocation=Beit Ha-Defus 7, Jerusalem, TripStatus=DONE, DropOffTime=21:06:04} }

and this is what the new rides datasnapshot looks like:

> DataSnapshot { key = -Lbwu6QnvcvTZQuPsNEI, value = {CurrentLocation=drug, Tel Aviv } }

this is what the database structure looks like:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EmwK.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Please also add the code where you attach the event listener. The code as-is at time of writing is fine, but how you attach the listener is what is important in this case.

Comment: I added some code, please take a look